# Request Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, fullscreen, ios6

Is there any way to request fullscreen in browser on an ipad with iOS6? It is actually very easy on every desktop browser, but I do need it for the safari mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: To request fullscreen in safari iOS6 isnt possible. You can just use some meta tags to get a better experience and hiding the address bar. After you did this you could handle on your own, which element should be shown in fullscreen.